# Does a missed attack expend a charge for Ring of the Ram?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

The description for Ring of the Ram states:

> While wearing the ring, you can use an action to expend 1 to 3 of its charges to attack one creature you can see within 60 feet of you...On a hit, for each charge you spend, the target takes 2d10 force damage...

Does this mean:

1. No charges are spent if a miss occurs
2. Player must state how many charges an attack will use, and if a miss occurs, those charges are no longer available?
3. A miss uses up a single charge

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Yes, a missed attack expends a charge, or charges.**

The sequence is as described:

1. expend *n* charges,
2. determine whether **the** attack hits
3. if hit: roll 2 *n* d10 for damage

(This is your #2 interpretation.)

Answer (score 14):

## You're spending charges to attack, not to hit

The rule states:

> While wearing the ring, you can use an action to expend 1 to 3 of its charges **to attack** one creature you can see within 60 feet of you

The ring simply allows you to attack, it does not guarantee success.

You declare beforehand that you want to use 1 or 2 or 3 charges, then you make the attack.  If you hit, you deal NUM_OF_CHARGES x 2D10 damage.  If you miss, you have still expended the charges but you do no damage.